# How to handle Platform Exception when sign-in flow cancelled by user

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am unable to handle the platform exception when user presses cancel instead of logging in using the google sign in window.

I have even tried an if statement so to not run if signIn returns null, but that does not work either.

```
  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
  try {
  await googleSignIn.signIn();
  } catch (error) {
  print(error);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's not so obvious when authenticating with google, is that the process consist of three steps

1. `_googleSignIn.signIn()` // prompt window
2. `googleAccount.authentication` // obtaining the credentials
3. `_auth.signInWithCredential(credential)` // the actual authentication

```
// STEP 1
// This is where flow gets cancelled and it results in the `googleAccount` to be null
 GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    if (googleAccount == null) {
        return null;
    }

// STEP 2
// obtaining credentials (cached or via input)
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuthentication = await googleAccount.authentication;

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleAuthentication.accessToken,
    );

// STEP 3
// the provider authentication
AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

// RESULT
print (user.uuid);
```

The issue I had and seem like others may have too, is that when wrapping three steps in try catch block and not handling the null value from the first step, and the catch block would expect the error object and code property - which would be the case. Anyways here is how I handle it now.

```
 // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26705
  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {    
    FirebaseUser user;
    var errorMessage;

    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleAccount == null) {
        errorMessage = "CANCELLED_SIGN_IN";        
        return Future.error(errorMessage);
      }

      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuthentication = await googleAccount.authentication;

      AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleAuthentication.accessToken,
      );

      AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      user = authResult.user; 
      return user;     
    }
    catch(error) {
      switch (error.code) {
          case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
            errorMessage = "Account already exists with a different credential.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL":
            errorMessage = "Invalid credential.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
            errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
            errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
            errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
            errorMessage = "User with this email has been disabled.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
            errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
            break;
          case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
            errorMessage = "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = "An undefined Error happened. ";
        }
    }
    if (errorMessage != null) {      
      return Future.error(errorMessage);
    }    

    return null;
  }
```

And the google button

```
GoogleSignInButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              var isError = false;
              var authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);

              await authService.signInWithGoogle().catchError((errorMessage) async {
                isError = true;
                if (errorMessage != 'CANCELLED_SIGN_IN') {
                  await showPopup(context, title: 'Validation', child: Text(errorMessage));
                }                
              }); 

              if (isError == false) {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomeScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Tried this approach and still throws the same error

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply catch `Error` like -

```
Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you sure that when you cancel the sign in ,the exception is caught because I see it still throws an exception with the latest version of google sign in